# show value of a cel instead cell address

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2013

I want to extract some text if a following data in the cells:

```
salutation  login   ID  email                  password   first_name  middle_name last_name gender date_of_birth account_status user_address1 user_address2              city       postal_code country   telephone    id_card_number   role
Mr.         bawan   1   bawan@gmail.com        bbbbbb     Bashir                  Awan      male   18-07-1988    active         55-B          Faisal Town                Lahore     54000       Pakistan  0423-5599229 34220-0353392-1  admin
Mr.         njawad  2   nasir@hotmail.com      nnnnnn     Nasir                   Jawad     male   21-03-1979    active         193           SherShah Colony            Gujranwala 54000       Pakistan  0319-2292299 35210-3523327-2  supervisor
Dr.         hakhan  3   faisal_khan@yahoo.com  hhhhhh     faisal      Aslam       Khan      male   12-05-1973    active         House# 77     Mumtaz Street, Sham Nagar  Gujrat     54000       Pakistan  0349-8280022 34220-0353392-1  admin
Ms.         tnoor   4   tayyaba.noor@live.com  tttttt     Tayyaba                 Noor      female 15-01-1980    active         483           Ghazanvi Road              Faisalabad 54000       Pakistan  0381-5589333 34220-0353392-1  marketing executive
```

This the data as show above its correctly formatted in excel it show a bit tidy.

This is what I am doing:

```
=CONCATENATE("{:salutation=>", A2 , ",  :login =>",B2," , :ID=>",  C2,", :email =>",D2,", :password=>",E2,", :first_name=>",F2,", :middle_name=>",G2,", :last_name=>",H2,", :gender =>",I2," , data_of_birth=>",J2,", :account_status=>",K2,", :user_address1=>",L2,", :user_address2=>",M2,", :city=>",N2,", :postal_code=>",O2,", :country=>",P2,", :telephone=>",Q2,", :id_card_number=>",R2,", :role=>",S2,"},")
```

and I got this in result:

```
{:salutation=>Mr.,  :login =>bawan , :ID=>1, :email =>bawan@gmail.com, :password=>bawan1, :first_name=>Bashir, :middle_name=> , :last_name=>Awan, :gender =>male , data_of_birth=>18-07-1988, :account_status=>active, :user_address1=>55-B, :user_address2=>Faisal Town, :city=>Lahore, :postal_code=>54000, :country=>Pakistan, :telephone=>0423-5599229, :id_card_number=>34220-0353392-1, :role=>admin},
```

But I want this to be generated:

```
{:salutation=>"Mr.",  :login =>"bawan" , :ID=>"1", :email =>"bawan@gmail.com", :password=>"bawan1", :first_name=>"Bashir", :middle_name=>"" , :last_name=>"Awan", :gender =>"male" , data_of_birth=>"18-07-1988", :account_status=>"active", :user_address1=>"55-B", :user_address2=>"Faisal Town", :city=>"Lahore", :postal_code=>"54000", :country=>"Pakistan", :telephone=>"0423-5599229", :id_card_number=>"34220-0353392-1", :role=>"admin"},
```

So what to change in my

```
=CONCATENATE(code)
```

to generate the above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes have a special meaning in excel formulas. Try using `CHAR(34)` instead. It's not 'pretty', but that's the workaround I found:

```
=CONCATENATE("{:salutation=>",CHAR(34),A2,CHAR(34),",  :login =>",CHAR(34),B2,CHAR(34)," , :ID=>",CHAR(34),C2,CHAR(34),", :email =>",CHAR(34),D2,CHAR(34),", :password=>",CHAR(34),E2,CHAR(34),", :first_name=>",CHAR(34),F2,CHAR(34),", :middle_name=>",CHAR(34),G2,CHAR(34),", :last_name=>",CHAR(34),H2,CHAR(34),", :gender =>",CHAR(34),I2,CHAR(34)," , data_of_birth=>",CHAR(34),J2,CHAR(34),", :account_status=>",CHAR(34),K2,CHAR(34),", :user_address1=>",CHAR(34),L2,CHAR(34),", :user_address2=>",CHAR(34),M2,CHAR(34),", :city=>",CHAR(34),N2,CHAR(34),", :postal_code=>",CHAR(34),O2,CHAR(34),", :country=>",CHAR(34),P2,CHAR(34),", :telephone=>",CHAR(34),Q2,CHAR(34),", :id_card_number=>",CHAR(34),R2,CHAR(34),", :role=>",CHAR(34),S2,,CHAR(34),"},")
```

EDIT: You can escape quotes with `""` (this excludes the quotes to indicate text):

```
=CONCATENATE("{:salutation=>""",A2,""",  :login =>""",B2,""" , :ID=>""",C2,""", :email =>""",D2,""", :password=>""",E2,""", :first_name=>""",F2,""", :middle_name=>""",G2,""", :last_name=>""",H2,""", :gender =>""",I2,""" , data_of_birth=>""",J2,""", :account_status=>""",K2,""", :user_address1=>""",L2,""", :user_address2=>""",M2,""", :city=>""",N2,""", :postal_code=>""",O2,""", :country=>""",P2,""", :telephone=>""",Q2,""", :id_card_number=>""",R2,""", :role=>""",S2,"""},")
```

Thanks JustinJDavies for pointing this out :)

Comment: Or `""""` will give you a single (escaped) quotation mark as a string

Comment: @JustinJDavies Huh, that's a lot of escaping required o.o Good to know that's available though!